# I have one table there are columns I want to replace rate which has op_date(04/01/2015) with rate which has op_date(04/01/2014)

Tags: sql

replace rate which has op_date(04/01/2015) with rate which has op_date(04/01/2014)
Table record

[image]

Comment: What is your actual data and expected output?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Example: code - El001, date- 2015-04-01 has  rate 0 i want to replace  this rate value with code - El001, date- 2014-04-01 rate 15.33 but there is lots of codes and there rates are different. for easy way to undersatand company wants previous year rate apply on current year so what is query for sql

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, the answer is: it is not possible to do this in a single query, you need a pl/sql script.

```
 declare
  tmp1 number;
  tmp2 number;
 begin
  select rate into tmp1 from yourtable where op_date = to_date (040115,'ddmmrr') and code='cs002';
  select rate into tmp2 from yourtable where op_date = to_date (040114,'ddmmrr') and code='cs002';
  update tablename set rate=tmp1 where op_date = to_date (040114,'ddmmrr') and code='cs002';
  update tablename set rate=tmp2 where op_date = to_date (040115,'ddmmrr') and code='cs002';
  commit;
 end;
 /
```

be aware because this script will give an error if the rate value is not unique against date and code